# theme path to plugin path

Tags: php, wordpress

```
require_once(get_template_directory().'/inc/MCAPI.class.php');
```

If I throw the above file in some plugin then what will be the path name?

let's say the name of the plugin is `pluginzigsaw`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To require from current plugin use `__DIR__` constant:
`require_once(__DIR__ . '/inc/MCAPI.class.php');`

To require file from other plugin or theme use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` constant:  `require_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/plugin_name/inc/MCAPI.class.php');`

Comment: You have not used the plugin name anywhere?

Comment: `__DIR__` returns the directory of the file, so you don't need to hardcode plugin name in the path

Comment: Are you sure sir?

Comment: You need to require file from other plugin or theme? If yes, you could use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR ` constant.
So your code will be: `require_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/pluginzigsaw/inc/MCAPI.class.php');`

Comment: theme is calling a path from someplugin. Yes!

Comment: what is the fault in this → `require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'/assets/MCAPI.class.php');`

Comment: `plugin_dir_path()` return path with trailing slash, so you need to change this code to: `require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'assets/MCAPI.class.php');`